# Change name of Iphone Project

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

i have edited an app and made some changes in it.
I want to change its name ..

SO i tried lots of methods to change the name and was success..

but the problem is, when i run this new application it replaces the older one....
but i want both to be there....not replacement...
edited----

my app support inapp purchase could be this is a problem?
is there any method to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new app id in provisioning portal and then change the bundle identifier in your [Project]-Info.plist.

I think it's the only way to install them both.

Comment: but my app using in app purchase....so change the name of bundle identifier will not possible....i think....

Comment: Then, I guess you can't. When you install an app on the iPhone any application having the same bundle identifier will be replaced.

Comment: Can't you use 2 in-app purchase accounts ?

Comment: actually the account is of our client and he want to use same one for both..new one and old one also.... on same iphone(i mean at testing time)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can make out from this is you want same app installed on device with with two different identifier.If you are using an adhoc provisioning profile, you just need to change the bundle identifier eg. com.adhoc.abc & com.adhoc.xyz & also dont forget to change the product name.(different product name for both of them)

Comment: but my app using in app purchase....so change the name of bundle identifier will not possible.