# replace characters in a string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string

i have a sting in which i want to replace all characters(except special characters)  by X..
i mean if i have a string
str= mac,iphone & ipad are products of apple

theis should be converted to

str= XXX,XXXXXX & XXXX XXX XXXXXXXX XX XXXXX

i know this can be done by finding all special characters and note their position and then replace all other characters except these  special characters but there are so many special characters should i check them one by one ? or is there any other method to identify them

please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSString *str=@"mac,iphone & ipad";

```
for(int i=0;i<[str length];i++)
{
    int str1=(int)[str characterAtIndex:i];
    NSString *temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C",str1];

    if(str1 >96 && str1 <123  || str1 >64 && str1 <91)

        str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:temp withString:@"X"];
}
```

Hope this helps...This will replace all characters either in upper/lower case

Comment: good work sherry....it worked and i become to know some special....moves....voted and accepted
will you please answer my another question here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869790/change-name-of-iphone-project

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *s = @"foo/bar:baz.foo";
NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/:."];
s = [[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

Try this. It is more useful when the above answered ways don't replace the characters.

Comment: interworld and your org name whats that?

Answer (score 1):

```
[Nsstring stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"" withString:@"X"];
```

from this you can replace string according to my knowledge

Comment: it does not works good for my problem this is not for all characters from a-z

Comment: just take one array and store all in array and then compare each array object if it is alphabet then change it into X other wise save as it in append string

Comment: actually the main problem is ..how to check that current character is alphabet

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if(TextFound)
    {
        NSCharacterSet *doNotWant = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"/<br />"];
        string = [[string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet: doNotWant] componentsJoinedByString: @""];

        TextStr = [TextStr stringByAppendingString:string];
    }
}
```

As I did it in my parsing, it was showing linebreak character in the text. I tried the way stringbyrplacingoccurance of string, but nothing happened, so finally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regular expression. Check out the documentation for `NSRegularExpression`